# Codeigniter Session Get Destroy After Refresh the Page

Tags: php

When I refresh the page codeigniter session get destroy. The same code is working fine on other servers.

It looks like some configuration changes s require in the new server. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I replace the following line

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
```

with

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'xyz_ci_session';
```

and now working fine. As many sites hosted on my server, session name was conflicting.